# VBA Count the number of row with condition using 'COUNTIF' but the answer is incorrect

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to count the number of rows with a date lower than a defined date. The code looks like this:

```
Dim countAoun As Integer
Dim dateM1 As Date

dateM1 = DateAdd("d", -2, Date)
countAoun = 0

countAoun = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B:B"), ">=" & dateM1)

Debug.Print countAoun
```

The code runs but it give an incorrect value, I have no idea why this is. I have used the same logic in the worksheet and it gives me the correct answer

Comment: What does `& CLng(dateM1)` return?

Comment: It returns the '44474', which = '05/10/2021'

Comment: I mean - what is the result if you use `WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B:B"), ">=" & CLng(dateM1))`?

Comment: That returned the correct number of rows, Thanks